# Proper way to redirect after successful signin

Tags: php, redirect, header, signing

## Short

During debug process  I see that, all goes right. For debugging purposes, before

`header('Location:'.wsurl.'me.php');`

Asigning generated url

`$redirect=wsurl.'me.php';`

And Netbeans shows right url adress

But on browser windows getting this screen

http://img849.imageshack.us/img849/9861/c6949d6ea7ba47909d2cc37.png

And it doesn't redirect to any url: just stays where it is.

## Question

What prevents redirection?

## Detailed

Here is full code of `signin` method

```
  public function signin() {
        if ($this->validation->check()) {
            foreach ($_POST as $k => $v)
                $$k = $v;

            $stmt = $this->db->prepare("
    SELECT u.id,    u.fname,    u.lname,    u.mname,  u.type, u.email, u.salt,
           u.pass,  u.salt,     u.approved, u.ban,      u2.status
    FROM `users` AS u
        LEFT OUTER JOIN `log` AS u2
            ON u2.user_id = u.id
    WHERE u.email = ? LIMIT 1") or die($this->db->error);

            $stmt->bind_param("s", $email) or die($stmt->error);
            $stmt->execute() or die($stmt->error);
            $stmt->store_result();
            $ip = ip2long($ip);
            if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
                $stmt->bind_result($id, $fname, $lname, $mname, $type, $email, $salt, $db_pass, $salt, $approved, $ban, $status) or die($stmt->error);
                $stmt->fetch() or die($stmt->error);
                $stmt->close();
                if ($status != 1) {
                    if ($approved == 1) {
                        if ($ban == 0) {
                            $hash = hash('sha256', $salt . hash('sha256', trim($pass)));
                            if ($hash == $db_pass) {
                                $token = sha1(microtime(true) . mt_rand(10000, 90000));
                                if (isset($remember) && $remember == "on") {

                                    $timeout = time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * COOKIE_TIME_OUT;

                                    $stmt = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO `log` (`user_id`,`ip`, `token`, `timeout`, `status`,`signin_dt`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,1,NOW())") or die($db->error);
                                    $stmt->bind_param("iiiii", $id, $ip, $token, $timeout) or die($stmt->error);
                                    setcookie('auth', "$token", $timeout);
                                } else {
                                    $stmt = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO `log`  (`user_id`,`ip`, `status`,`signin_dt`) VALUES (?,?,1,NOW())") or die($db->error);
                                    $stmt->bind_param("ii", $id, $ip) or die($stmt->error);
                                    session_start();
                                    session_regenerate_id(true); //this is a security measure
                                    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $id;
                                    $_SESSION['token'] = $token;
                                    $_SESSION['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] = md5($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
                                    $_SESSION['remote_ip'] = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
                                }
                                $stmt->execute() or die($stmt->error);
                                $stmt->close();                                    
                                $redirect=wsurl.'me.php';
                                header('Location: '.$redirect); die;
                            } else {
                                die($this->ajax->respond(3));
                            }
                        } else {
                            die($this->ajax->respond(4));
                        }
                    } else {
                        die($this->ajax->respond(5));
                    }
                } else {
                    die($this->ajax->respond(6));
                }
            } else {

                die($this->ajax->respond(7));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the constant `wsurl`?

Comment: make sure you are doing `header` before any other output... i suspect `$this->ajax->respond(2);` is doing some output (sounds like it is)

Comment: @Pheonix Yes this line doing output. Removed. Same thing. No success.

Comment: You should not output as peeps have said tho this woud normally throw blatant errors, also add a die/exit after the header and dont forget the space: `header('Location: '.$redirect); die;`

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Added your suggestion. Nothing has changed. Again same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `ajax_respond()` sends output to the browser, you cannot follow that with a `header()` call, since output will already have been sent. An AJAX response is not typically followed by any redirection, since the client browser is not intended to reload the page. Instead the AJAX response is processed in the page and no redirection takes place.

Comment: Yes ajax_respond() line doing output. Removed. Same thing. No success

Answer (score 2):

HOLY GUACAMOLE! That's a **lot** of if-statements!!

Lots of if statements increase Cyclomatic Complexity, which is a very bad thing. Over the course of four decades, numerous long-range studies have shown conclusively that projects with high cyclomatic complexity virtually always fail because they're too expensive to maintain and extend.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity

---

How about you start from scratch and use return statements and exceptions to control flow instead? It'll be much more beautiful, far easier to comprehend quickly, **substantially easier to [unit] test**, and less prone to errors.

Here's what I use in my own code:

```
class UserController
{
    public function login()
    {
        $username = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'username', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $password = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'password', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

        $status = $this->userManager->validatePassword($password);
        if ($status == UserManager::LOGGED_IN)
        {
            $this->createUserSession();
        }
    }
}
```

Then I have this:

```
class SecurityController
{
    const NOT_LOGGED_IN = 501;

    public function ensureHasAccess()
    {
        if ($this->isLoggedIn() === false)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException('User is not logged in', self::NOT_LOGGED_IN);
        }
    }
}
```

So all you have to do to make sure a logged in user is running stuff on a page is do this:

```
$guard = new SecurityController;
$guard->ensureHasAccess();
```

THEN, finally, in web/index.php, I have this:

```
try
{
    // DO web stuff here.
}
catch (RuntimeException $e)
{
    if ($e->getCode() == SecurityController::NOT_LOGGED_IN)
    {
        // Oops! The user isn't logged in... Redirect!!
        header('Location: http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/user_directory/?errmsg=not+logged+in');
        exit; // Thanks, drrcknlsn!
    }
}
```

---

I've even created a demo app to teach people this sort of stuff. Part of the PHP University's code repo:  http://repo.phpexperts.pro/source/user_directory/files

Comment: If statements has nothing to do with my issue. It's coding style, there is no error in these statements they work well.  Now try to, answer to my question, instead of writing bunch of code

Comment: You should `exit;` after a header redirect, otherwise the rest of the current page is built and sent to the client's browser along with the header (security hole).

Comment: @trl13 Lots of if statements increase Cyclomatic Complexity, which is a **very** bad thing.  Over the course of **four decades**, numerous long-range studies have shown **conclusively** that projects with high cyclomatic complexity **virtually always fail because they're too expensive to maintain and extend**. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity

Answer (score 0):

Obviously if you're redirecting to `wsurl . 'me.php'` and the browser is only trying to request `me.php` then your problem is that `wsurl` is null.  I don't know what exactly `wsurl` is, but if it's supposed to be a variable, then it should be `$wsurl` instead of `wsurl`.  If it's a constant, make sure whatever file it's defined in is included in this file.  And no matter what it is, make sure you are correctly spelling it, with proper casing, etc.

You should really use the PHP error log, though.  It will tell you exactly what went wrong and where, in cases like this.

Comment: As I told in my post `And Netbeans shows right url adress` . wsurl defined before and it's exactly what I need (full url of website). So there is no wrong in  `wsurl . 'me.php'` Also debugging >= php error  log :))

Comment: It doesn't matter what Netbeans says.  It only matters what the browser receives, which is "me.php", which means that `wsurl` is empty at the point that it gets added to the header.  Browsers don't just arbitrarily remove substrings from header locations. ;-)